# order and shortcut references of same authors

Tags: biblatex

I want to have the references of same author like this (Milberg and Winkler, 2010, 2013) even if I enter first the reference of the year 2013. Also, the problem in my code is that even when both references have the same author they come like ((Milberg and Winkler, 2010; Milberg and Winkler, 2013). I am using biblatex

```
@article{MilbergWinkler2010FinancialisationDynamicsOffshoring,
title = {Financialisation and the dynamics of offshoring in the {USA}},
volume = {34},
issn = {0309-166X, 1464-3545},
url = {https://academic.oup.com/cje/article-lookup/doi/10.1093/cje/bep061},
doi = {10.1093/cje/bep061},
pages = {275--293},
number = {2},
journaltitle = {Cambridge Journal of Economics},
shortjournal = {Cambridge Journal of Economics},
author = {Milberg, W. and Winkler, D.},
urldate = {2023-10-15},
date = {2010-03-01},
langid = {english},
keywords = {{GVC}},
file = {Milberg_Winkler_2010_Financialisation and the dynamics of offshoring in the USA.pdf:C\:\\Users\\PC\\OneDrive\\OneDrive - unige.ch\\zotero\\storage\\FLBKPT9B\\Milberg_Winkler_2010_Financialisation and the dynamics of offshoring in the USA.pdf:application/pdf},
}

@book{MilbergWinkler2013OutsourcingEconomicsGlobal,
location = {Cambridge ; New York},
title = {Outsourcing economics: global value chains in capitalist development},
isbn = {978-1-107-02699-5 978-1-107-60962-4},
shorttitle = {Outsourcing economics},
pagetotal = {349},
publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
author = {Milberg, William S. and Winkler, Deborah},
date = {2013},
keywords = {United States, Economic aspects, Foreign trade and employment, Free trade, Globalization, Labor market, Offshore outsourcing},
}
```

And here is the code:

```
    \usepackage[
style=authoryear,
backend=biber,
maxbibnames=50,
sorting=nyt
]{biblatex}

    \DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}


\begin{document}

\parencite{MilbergWinkler2010FinancialisationDynamicsOffshoring, 
   MilbergWinkler2013OutsourcingEconomicsGlobal}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the style `authoryear-comp` instead of `authoryear`, the `comp` part means 'compress'. This also sorts the citations by year.

However, this only works if the names in the `.bib` entries are exactly the same. Even if the name(s) shown in the document are the same but the source is different then it will show as separate authors, because it might very well be that they are indeed different authors - for example `Smith, John` and `Smith, Janet` or `Smith, John` and `Smith, J.` (where the second one may be Janet for example).

Example:

```
@article{MilbergWinkler2010FinancialisationDynamicsOffshoring,
title = {Financialisation and the dynamics of offshoring in the {USA}},
volume = {34},
url = {https://academic.oup.com/cje/article-lookup/doi/10.1093/cje/bep061},
doi = {10.1093/cje/bep061},
pages = {275--293},
number = {2},
journaltitle = {Cambridge Journal of Economics},
author = {Milberg, W. and Winkler, D.},
urldate = {2023-10-15},
date = {2010-03-01},
}

@book{MilbergWinkler2013OutsourcingEconomicsGlobal,
  title = {Outsourcing economics: global value chains in capitalist development},
  pagetotal = {349},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  author = {Milberg, W. and Winkler, D.},
  date = {2013}
}
```

LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
style=authoryear-comp,
backend=biber,
maxbibnames=50,
sorting=nyt,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\addbibresource{blsortcompress.bib}


\begin{document}

\parencite{MilbergWinkler2013OutsourcingEconomicsGlobal,MilbergWinkler2010FinancialisationDynamicsOffshoring}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: would this solution also allow for reference in the text as ibid if the same reference is cited consecutively?

Comment: @AyozeAlfageme for that you need the style `authoryear-icomp` where the `i` stands for _ibid_.

Comment: I have noticed that I used  first \parentcite[38]{Penrose1959} and then again the same reference, the second one does not show ibid but the whole name again. If I do not use [38] in the first one, then it works properly.

Comment: @AyozeAlfageme See the [biblatex documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/biblatex/0) page 63, there is a switch `ibidpage` that controls this behavior.

Comment: thank you. I tried switching it on and off but the problem remains...

Comment: @AyozeAlfageme maybe you should ask a separate question about that, with the exact code that produces the problem. When I try `\parencite[38]{MilbergWinkler2013OutsourcingEconomicsGlobal}
some text \parencite{MilbergWinkler2013OutsourcingEconomicsGlobal}` I get the expected output _(Milberg and Winkler, 2013, p. 38) some text (ibid.)_ with `authoryear-icomp`.